# Getting a "expected type-specifier" error when I instantiate a custom class in a custom class

Tags: c++, c++11, g++

It seems that this error usually arises when you don't properly include classes, but after checking my work it seems all is in order...

For the sake of brevity i created a test.h + test.cpp to show you how my code is breaking. For some reason when I attempt to instantiate the class SetAsList in test.cpp it throws me the title's error. I commented the line of code as well

Thank you for any insight!

main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "test.h"
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

}
```

test.h

```
#ifndef _test
#define _test

#include "SetAsOC.h"
#include "SetAsList.h"
using namespace std;
class test
{
public:
    test(){};
    void example();

};
#endif
```

test.cpp:

```
#include "test.h"

void test::example()
{
    SetAsList *trial = new SetAsList::SetAsList(); // <-- test.cpp:6:25: error: expected type-specifier
}
```

SetAsList.h

```
#ifndef _SETLIST
#define _SETLIST

#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "Set.h"
using namespace std;

//node for DLL
typedef struct node{
node *previous;
node *next;
int value;
} node;

class SetAsList: Set
{

private:
    node *head;
    node *tail;
    int count;

public: 

    ~SetAsList();
    //method=0 is a pure virtual method for abstract classes
    int size();
    SetAsList();
    int& operator[](const int& Index);
    void add(int value);
    void removeObject(int value);
    void removeAt(int index);
    int indexOf(int value);
    void remove(node *obj); //removes node
};

#endif
```

SetAsList.cpp

```
#include "SetAsList.h"

int SetAsList::size()
{
return count;
}

SetAsList::SetAsList()
{
    head = NULL;
    tail = NULL;
    count =0;
}

SetAsList::~SetAsList()
{
    node *temp = head;
    node *freeNode;
    for(int a=0; a< count; a++)
    {

        freeNode = temp;
        temp = temp->next;
        delete freeNode;
    }
    head = NULL;
    tail = NULL;
    count =0;
}

int& SetAsList::operator[](const int& Index)
{
    node *temp = head;

    for(int a=0; a< count; a++)
    {

        if(Index == a)
            return temp->value;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    throw 321;
}

void SetAsList::add(int value)
{
    node *newNode = new node();
    newNode->value = value;
    if(count ==0)
    {
        head= newNode;
        tail = newNode;
    }
    else
    {
        tail->next = newNode;
        newNode->previous = tail;
        tail = newNode;
    }

    count ++;

}

void SetAsList::removeAt(int index)
{
    node *temp = head;

    for(int a=0; a< count; a++)
    {

        if(index == a)
            {

            return;
            }
            temp = temp->next;
    }
}

void SetAsList::removeObject(int value)
{
    node *temp = head;

    for(int a=0; a< count; a++)
    {

        if(value == temp->value)
        {
        remove(temp);
        return;
        }
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}

int SetAsList::indexOf(int value)
{
    node *temp = head;
    for(int a=0; a< count; a++)
    {

        if(temp->value == value)
        {
        return a;
        }
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    return -1;
}

void SetAsList::remove(node *obj)
{

    if(count ==1)
    {   delete head;
        head = NULL;
        tail = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        node *prev = obj->previous;
        node *next = obj->next;
        prev->next = next;
        next->previous = prev;
        delete obj;
    }
    count--;
}
```

Comment: `SetAsList *trial = new SetAsList();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error message said, `SetAsList::SetAsList` is not a type-specifier, change

```
SetAsList *trial = new SetAsList::SetAsList();
```

to

```
SetAsList *trial = new SetAsList();
```

The default constructor will be called, you don't need to specify it.

Comment: That worked, I guess my follow up question is, WHY did this work? I thought the purpose of adding the ClassName::MethodName was to specify what class to look for a method? I haven't done too much in c++

Comment: @oorosco The constructors are special, their name are same as class, their syntaxs are different from normal member functions. No need to specify the method name for them. And if you have multiple constructors, you can differentiate them by arguments. e.g. `new SetAsList()` will call `SetAsList::SetAsList()`, and `new SetAsList(0)` will call `SetAsList::SetAsList(int)`.

Comment: I understand how constructors get overloaded, but why would "SetAsList::SetAsList()" not work while "SetAsList()" works? It doesn't make sense

Comment: @oorosco It's just the rule for constructor. When you construct an object, you must appoint the name of the class, but specifying the constructor's name will be duplicate. It must be `SetAsList::SetAsList()`, you can't specify it with other name such as `SetAsList::OtherCtorName()`, right?

Comment: I guess what i'm getting at is, what's is the purpose of "SetAsList::"??

Comment: Especially since in my int main function i originally had "SetAsList *temp = new SetAsList::SetAsList()" and it worked

Comment: @oorosco `::` is used for qualified identifiers [http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers], and `SetAsList *temp = new SetAsList::SetAsList()` should not compile wherever it is. I tried a draft here. [http://ideone.com/eOBPr3]

Comment: Thanks for the vocab word, wasn't sure what they were called. It's really weird that it did compile and run in my main though. Thanks for all the help